# How do I customize GRUB2 entries for other operating systems?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system, and I am using it as the sort of host OS allowing its version of GRUB to be the boot loader and allowing it to manage all of the grub configuration. When I run "update-grub" to update the grub config file with the newly installed operating systems it does that just fine, but I can't find any way to add custom things to these entries without editing the actual "grub.cfg" which it says not to do.

The customizations I am looking to add would be things like "quiet splash=silent" for openSUSE in order to get its splash screen. Just adding "quiet" for Arch Linux, and adding "quiet rhgb" for Fedora in order to use its splash screen. I was wondering if there is any official way to do this other than editing the file it says not to edit?

Answer (score 1):

To add custom entries, the file you should edit is `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.

The options are the same as in `grub.cfg`, but just in case [here is a link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus) with more info how to customize the file.