# How to control auto-generated grub entries for other operating systems?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

On my computer I have Ubuntu 19.04 intalled along with Windows 10 and Fedora 29.

In Ubuntu, running `sudo update-grub` gives the following:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-13-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-18-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Fedora 29 (Workstation Edition) on /dev/mapper/fedora-root
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

which I think looks fine, it detects both Windows Boot Manager and Fedora 29 and it sets up a grub menu letting me choose between the different operating systems at boot time.

My problem is that Fedora needs some special configuration in order to workaround some graphics driver problems. Specifically, the options `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` need to be added for that grub menu entry.

I am able to fix this by manually editing the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but that change is overwritten next time `update-grub` runs, so it is not a good solution. Also, the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` that I am then editing starts with a comment saying "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE", also indicating that I should perhaps not edit it.

My question is: how can I add some extra boot options for the Fedora grub entry that is generated when I run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu?

There are some options in the `/etc/default/grub` file that is used by `update-grub`, for example I can choose GRUB_TIMEOUT there which works fine, but as far as I know that file does not allow me to specify boot options for other operating systems, only for Ubuntu itself.

To further clarify what I mean, the auto-generated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file (created by `update-grub`) contains a section looking like this, specifying how Fedora is booted if that grub menu option is chosen:

```
menuentry 'Fedora 29 (Workstation Edition) (on /dev/mapper/fedora-root)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-6398dc3c-28e3-4947-ad82-d9defe5d9a28' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  b00e70c6-820f-4615-b95d-c933eaea0d3f
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b00e70c6-820f-4615-b95d-c933eaea0d3f
    fi
    linux /vmlinuz-5.0.9-200.fc29.x86_64 root=/dev/dm-2
    initrd /initramfs-5.0.9-200.fc29.x86_64.img
}
```

and I would like the above to look slightly different, adding the options `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` in the end of the line starting with `linux`. Is there some way to tell `update-grub` to do that?

I did see the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460700/how-do-i-customize-grub2-entries-for-other-operating-systems) about editing the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file but that solution means writing the whole menuentry manually so it will not adapt when the kernel version in Fedora changes. The auto-generated menuentry created by `update-grub` has the advantage that it gives the latest Fedora kernel, I would like to use that and just add something to the "linux" line inside the auto-generated menuentry. Can that be done, and if so, how?

Comment: I think you can try booting from the Fedora's Grub instead, easy to setup in UEFI. This should work unless you also need boot parameters for Ubuntu in which case you'll be having the same problem but in Ubuntu.

Comment: [This doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my inelegant solution.

1. Open `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` to edit.
2. Find the line where `LPARAMS` is defined and change its value to whatever you want appended at the end of the linux line in the grub menu entry. Include all desired parameters (including the root value), with appropriate spacing. **As a precaution, leave the original LPARAMS line, but commented out.**
3. Run update-grub.

This process will append your additions as parameters for every linux os that is probed for.

There is surely a more specific way to do this by adding custom logic to `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, but I do not know how.